# Expectation value of $\langle H^n \rangle_{t=0}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

I am trying to find the expectation value of $\langle H^n \rangle_{t=0}$ I am given some normalized state $| \psi, 0 \rangle$ (at time equals zero). Since the hamiltonian is a hermitian operator, the states can be written as a linear combination of eigenstates $\{ | E \rangle \}$.

$$| \psi, 0 \rangle = \int | E\rangle \langle E| \psi, 0 \rangle dE$$

To find the expectation value I would need to calculate $\langle \psi,0 | H^n | \psi,0\rangle$, however, I am given the following statement:

$$ \langle H^n \rangle(0) = \langle \psi,0 | \psi, 0 \rangle = \int \langle E | H^n | E \rangle \langle E| \psi,0 \rangle dE = \int E^n |E \rangle \langle E | \psi ,0 \rangle dE$$

I do not understand this equality. I was told that the time zero state is normalized, so the second part should equal 1. Furthermore, in the third part, where is the $H^n$ coming from? To me the logic should be something like:

$$\langle \psi,0 | H^n | \psi,0\rangle = \langle \psi,0 | \int H^n| E\rangle \langle E| \psi, 0 \rangle dE =  \langle \psi,0 | E^n \int | E\rangle \langle E| \psi, 0 \rangle dE  = E^n \int |\langle E| \psi, 0 \rangle |^2 dE$$

Clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are clearly some typos in the "following statement", and you cannot take the $E^n$ out of the integral in the last equation (otherwise the result would be $E^n$ which does not make sense).

Comment: At a higher level, what kind of result are you looking for exactly? You cannot expect to be able to compute moments of an arbitrary Hamiltonian in an arbitrary state.

Comment: "I am given the following statement..." Given by who? The statement (the equations) you have written do not seem consistent with each other. For example, the first equality on the second line. Can you make sure you are copying them down correctly or provide the reference to which you are referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$| \psi, 0 \rangle = \int | E\rangle \langle E| \psi, 0 \rangle dE\qquad$$

> $$ \langle H^n \rangle(0) = \langle \psi,0 | \psi, 0 \rangle = \int \langle E | H^n | E \rangle \langle E| \psi,0 \rangle dE = \int E^n |E \rangle \langle E | \psi ,0 \rangle dE$$

The first equality on the second line above does not make sense.

It should read:
$$
\langle H^n \rangle(0) = \langle \psi,0 |H^n| \psi, 0 \rangle\;.
$$

The second equality on the second line does not make sense either...

The third equality on the second line clearly is nonsense since to equates a ket to a number...

It looks like you have either copied it down wrong or the reference you are using has lots of errors/typos.